# How can script the rename of pane in tmux to reflect the current directory?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I'd like to make a quick key in TMUX that queries the current directory and makes some portion of it the name of the <strike>pane</strike> window.  Normally, I rename the <strike>pane</strike> window with `ctrl-b ,` only to then add some indication about the where it is in the file system.  It might be nice if I could both automate it putting the name there or even have new <strike>pane</strike> window open with this title.

So how can script a new keyboard shortcut like `ctrl-b T` that will add the title?

Answer (score 2):

You can use #{pane_current_path} on most platforms (not OpenBSD) to get the pane's working directory. So you can do for example "tmux renamew '#{pane_current_path}'" to rename a single window, or put it in automatic-rename-format to automatically include it in every window name.

You might find the = modifier to be useful to trim the path (look at FORMATS in the manual).

If you want it to be shortened more intelligently your best bet is to rename it to $PWD from the shell prompt either with "tmux renamew" or by turning on allow-rename and using the rename escape sequence \033k$PWD\033\.